# How can I access a Radio Button in another form?

Tags: c#, .net

I want to see if notch50hzbutton is checked in another form, something like: `if (SettingsForm.notch50hzbutton.Checked == true) .....` How can I do this?

```
namespace ClassLibrary1
 {
    using GraficDisplay;
    using GraphLib;
    using PrecisionTimer;


    public partial class SettingsForm : Form
    {

        public SettingsForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            notch50hzbutton.Checked = false;
            notch60hzbutton.Checked = true;

        }

        private void notch50Hz_Checked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            notch50hzbutton.Checked = true;
        }

        private void notch60Hz_Checked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            notch60hzbutton.Checked = true;
        }
    }
  }
```

Comment: ASP.NET? Winforms? WPF? Silverlight?

Answer (score 2):

```
public bool Notch50HzIsChecked 
{
   get { return notch50hzbutton.Checked; }
   set { notch50hzbutton.Checked = value; }
}
```

You may then access it like a regular property from outside the class.

Comment: Hmm, I tried this but still cannot access it in another form using SettingsForm.Notch50HzIsChecked

Comment: Do you have a proper reference to the form you are accessing? If not you may need to pass one in. If you are calling the method staticly as SettingsForm.Notch50HzIsChecked you will get a compile error.

Comment: I included:  using ClassLibrary1; to reference the form. Is this ok?

Answer (score 0):

Make a public property on the form and pass through the value you want to access externally?

Answer (score 0):

A way to check to see if the control is checked without exposing the control itself is to add a public method (or a public property with just the getter) that does that to your `SettingsForm`.

```
public bool IsNotch50hzbuttonChecked()
{
    return notch50hzbutton.Checked;
}
```

and then you can check

```
if (settingsFormInstance.IsNotch50hzbutton())
{
 ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would make a corresponding public property  that's accessible to the outside:

```
public partial class SettingsForm : Form
{
   public bool Is60Hz {get; private set;}
   ...

   private void notch50Hz_Checked(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
        notch50hzbutton.Checked = true;
        Is60Hz = false;
   }

   private void notch60Hz_Checked(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
        notch60hzbutton.Checked = true;
        Is60Hz = true;
   }
```